# Publish multiple sub project jars at the same location

Tags: java, gradle

I have a gradle multi-project (java)

ROOT
|-subA
|-subB
|-subC

I successfully configured my root build.gradle and gradle.settings to resolve dependencies and build the overall project OK.

But then all jars are produced in subX/build/libs (with X=A,B,C)

Is there a way to regroup everything at the end (with runtime resources also)
so everything is ready for shipping ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution has some problems: Task dependencies aren't correct, stale Jar files won't be removed, and there is no guarantee that all `Jar` tasks will be found. (The latter could be fixed by using `project.tasks.withType(Jar).all`, instead of `.each`.) Here is a more accurate solution:

```
task deploy(type: Sync) {
    into "$buildDir/deploy"
    for (subproject in subprojects) {
        from subproject.tasks.withType(Jar)
    }
}
```

PS: Except for some cases where utmost flexibility is required, it's better to use a `Copy` or `Sync` task than the `project.copy` method.

Comment: thanks for your help. I'm new to Groovy DSL and I don't really fully understand the implications of some commands. I looked at the "Sync" task specification, so I understand the "into" and "from" method. But I have another question : Why are we using Jar type tasks to find the jar files to be sync'ed ? If I want to also copy the main sourceSets resources, how would you find thoses files ?

Comment: Why would you want to? They are contained in the Jar. Do you mean third-party dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer within the gradle online help (although it was somehow not really tagged to find it)

```
task deploy(dependsOn: assemble) << {
    File deployDist = mkdir("$buildDir/deploy")
    subprojects.each {project ->
        project.tasks.withType(Jar).each {archiveTask ->
            copy {
                from archiveTask.archivePath
                into deployDist
            }
        }
    }
}
```